# "IndexError: list index out of range" when using index [0] on a list with length of 1

Tags: python

I have an issue with calling the [0] index on a single item list:

This code throws the: "IndexError: list index out of range" error
but only for the weak_team & weak_team_id lines
The strong_team & strong_team_id allow me to call the [0] index of the list.

```
def get_round_of_64(self, year):
    regions = ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    roundof64 = {}
    for region in regions:
        for game in range(1,9):
            round_game = 'R1' + region + str(game)
            strong_seed = MNCAATourneySlots.loc[(MNCAATourneySlots.Season == year) & (MNCAATourneySlots.Slot == round_game), 'StrongSeed'].tolist()[0]
            weak_seed = MNCAATourneySlots.loc[(MNCAATourneySlots.Season == year) & (MNCAATourneySlots.Slot == round_game), 'WeakSeed'].tolist()[0]
            strong_team = Team(MNCAATourneySeeds.loc[(MNCAATourneySeeds.Season == year) & (MNCAATourneySeeds.Seed == strong_seed), 'TeamID'].tolist()[0])
            strong_team_id = MNCAATourneySeeds.loc[(MNCAATourneySeeds.Season == year) & (MNCAATourneySeeds.Seed == strong_seed), 'TeamID'].tolist()[0]
            print(f'Strong Team ID: {strong_team_id}')
            weak_team = Team(MNCAATourneySeeds.loc[(MNCAATourneySeeds.Season == year) & (MNCAATourneySeeds.Seed == weak_seed), 'TeamID'].tolist()[0])
            weak_team_id = MNCAATourneySeeds.loc[(MNCAATourneySeeds.Season == year) & (MNCAATourneySeeds.Seed == weak_seed), 'TeamID'].tolist()[0]
            print(f'Weak Team ID: {weak_team_id}')
            roundof64[round_game] = {f'{strong_seed}': strong_team, f'{weak_seed}': weak_team}
    # print(roundof64)
    return roundof64
```

Here is the code when I take away the [0] index for the weak_team & weak_teams_id lines:

```
def get_round_of_64(self, year):
        regions = ['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
        roundof64 = {}
        for region in regions:
            for game in range(1,9):
                round_game = 'R1' + region + str(game)
                strong_seed = MNCAATourneySlots.loc[(MNCAATourneySlots.Season == year) & (MNCAATourneySlots.Slot == round_game), 'StrongSeed'].tolist()[0]
                weak_seed = MNCAATourneySlots.loc[(MNCAATourneySlots.Season == year) & (MNCAATourneySlots.Slot == round_game), 'WeakSeed'].tolist()[0]
                strong_team = Team(MNCAATourneySeeds.loc[(MNCAATourneySeeds.Season == year) & (MNCAATourneySeeds.Seed == strong_seed), 'TeamID'].tolist()[0])
                strong_team_id = MNCAATourneySeeds.loc[(MNCAATourneySeeds.Season == year) & (MNCAATourneySeeds.Seed == strong_seed), 'TeamID'].tolist()[0]
                print(f'Strong Team ID: {strong_team_id}')
                weak_team = Team(MNCAATourneySeeds.loc[(MNCAATourneySeeds.Season == year) & (MNCAATourneySeeds.Seed == weak_seed), 'TeamID'].tolist())
                weak_team_id = MNCAATourneySeeds.loc[(MNCAATourneySeeds.Season == year) & (MNCAATourneySeeds.Seed == weak_seed), 'TeamID'].tolist()
                print(f'Weak Team ID: {weak_team_id}')
                roundof64[round_game] = {f'{strong_seed}': strong_team, f'{weak_seed}': weak_team}
        # print(roundof64)
        return roundof64
```

It returns:

```
Strong Team ID: 1314
Weak Team ID: [1458]
```

*looped for all of the teams

The "Weak Team ID:" value is clearly a list so I'm not sure why calling the [0] index is causing problems.

Comment: you can use pdb to inspect if the Series has any contents `python3 -m pdb ./myscript.py` or just perhaps `print()` to show that this is the case

Comment: Your code will loop 32 times (4 regions times 8 games).  However, you have shown us only one example of the printed output - does the Weak Team ID *always* show as a list with at least one item, all 32 times?